# Angular test not running change detection correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a simple component which contains a `container`-div. If the Input `highlighted` is set to `TRUE`, the `container`-div should have the class `background-green`. And there is a test for this behaviour. But my test fails with `Expected false to be truthy`. Is the call `fixture.detectChanges()` not working, for detached components? Has someone an idea if there is something wrong with my test? Thank you in advance.

````
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: ```<div class="container" [class.background-green]="highlighted"></div>```
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() highlighted: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ) {
        this.changeDetectorRef.detach();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
}


describe('MyComponent', () => {
    let component: MyComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
    let debugElement: DebugElement;
    let containerElement: HTMLElement;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                MyComponent
            ],
            providers: [
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        debugElement = fixture.debugElement;

        containerElement = debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.container'))[0].nativeElement;

        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should have class "background-green" if highlighted=TRUE', () => {
        component.highlighted = true;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        containerElement = debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.container'))[0].nativeElement;
        expect(containerElement.classList.contains('background-green')).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
````

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I didn't...

Comment: Really there is no answer for this ?

Comment: Any chance you were using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`?
That could be why your element isn't rendering - might need to call changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()